# Python Openpyxl-value of an input variable is not accessible inside for loop

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm new to Python. My code has to ask for a product ID (string) from the user, then find the cell in an Exel file which includes that Produt ID. Once the cell is found, the value of the next 30 columns on the same row should be read and printed.

When the user enters product ID which is asked before the for loop, it doesn't work. However, if I enter a product ID directly in the code (a value which exists in the Excel file instead of asking the user), it works! How can I fix that ?

'''

```
    import openpyxl

    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename="Forecast - 2020-02-06.xlsx")

    workbook.__iter__()

    sheet = workbook.active

    ProductID = input("Please enter a Product ID")
    #Lets say the product ID is "ABC"

    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=5, min_col=1, max_col=30):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == ProductID:

    #if in the line above I type cell.value == "ABC" the rest of the code would work!
```

Thanks

Comment: If your product IDs were numeric (integers for example) the above approach would not work, as the variable stored in `ProductID` will be a `str`. If they are like "ABC" are you sure you are not typing a space before entering the ID when prompted? This would set `ProductID` to " ABC" (with a leading space. and " ABC" != "ABC". Otherwise, I have tried your code and it seems to work fine...

Comment: The 'Product ID' is a string in format 123-123-1. I have referred to it by "ABC" for simplicity. it seems like my code reads the Product ID as neither integer nor string, but a NoneType! How can I avoid a nonetype ? THX

Comment: `input` will return a string. When you use `cell.value` I think the returned typed is appropriate for the cells contents (so if the cell has an Integer in it, then this will be an `int` etc..). I have replicated your code, and for me (Python 3.7.3 on Win10) it works as expected. Try stepping through with a debugger, or add a `print(cell.value, ProductID)` line above the `if` so you can actually see the values on each iteration. This may help to see what is going on...

Comment: Mystery solved! I was entering a space when entering the ProductID. So the code was not finding it equal to the value form Excel table. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad you solved it! For future reference, assuming you dont want spaces to be stored with your input you could use `input().strip()` which will 'strip' away any white space if you accidentally enter one and ensure that your string comparisons work as expected